# Form Authentication issue for two sub folders

Tags: forms-authentication

In my application there are two sub folders which needs to be authenticated. In my application web.config, i have given like this

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Customer/My Accounts/Default.aspx"  name="formsauth1" 
             />
  </authentication>
```

This will work for only one sub folder having the path Customer/My Accounts/Default.aspx but I need to authenticate another sub folder having path Arab/Customer/My Accounts/Default.aspx. I want to know how to identify both the folders and how to authenticate them by modifying the above said code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the loginUrl equal to your login page, not the restricted page.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"  name="formsauth1" />
  </authentication>
```

Then in the sub folders you want to create a web.config in each with the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So what will happen is that when an unauthenticated user tries to access those sub folders, the `<authorization>` element will deny them and redirect them to the `loginUrl`.  After they log in, they'll be returned to the original page they were trying to access.

Comment: I have created web.config in both the sub folders like what you said. The issue is that both the sub folders contains login pages and I need to find out the path of the page that I access. When I give login.aspx then it will redirect to the currently working folder, right? If I am trying to access a page in subfolder1, then it should be redirected to login.aspx in subfolder1 and when I try to access a page in subfolder2 then it should redirect to the page in that particular folder.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Subfolder1/Login.aspx"  name="formsauth1" />
  </authentication>
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Subfolder2/Login.aspx"  name="formsauth1" />
  </authentication>

Comment: @Greg do you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Why do they both have login pages?  Maybe we can change it so there's only one login page to save some headache?  See also http://forums.asp.net/t/328206.aspx

Comment: My application contains both english and arabic version so both are seperately handled in different folders

Comment: I think the reason you're running into problems is that this isn't really the "asp.net way" to do globalization.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx  It sounds like you should install two different applications, one for English and one for Arabic if you want to make your current architecture work.

Comment: We had created different application for both the versions before but due to some other reason we were suppposed to merge both the applications in to one and unfortunately this error occurred. I have merged both the versions because in both versions there is an upload section where we can upload photoes and files in to a folder in our application.Currently when the user uses the english version the files will be uploaded to that applications folder and vice versa.  But I was asked to upload the files in to the folder in english version application even if the user uses the arabic version.

Comment: You might be able to Server.MapPath them to the same directory.